# Spring connect to mongodb using username and password

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I've got mongo DB running on docker. To set username and password I set MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE, MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME and MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD variables.

And now on spring boot application a can use URI: 
`mongodb://username:password@host:27017/db_name?authSource=admin` and it's working.

Now I want changed properties and it looks like:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      authentication-database: admin
      host: host
      database: db_name
      password: password
      port: 27107
      username: username
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

springboot: 2.2.5
spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive

Answer (score 3):

I found that on the documentation:

> If you use the Mongo 3.0 Java driver, `spring.data.mongodb.host` and `spring.data.mongodb.port` are not supported. In such cases, `spring.data.mongodb.uri` should be used to provide all of the configuration.

So probably this is the problem and for now I just stay with the URI.